# Which part have to be published to NPM registry

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rollupjs, npm-publish

I am trying to create reusable react components that I would like to publish to NPM registry.
The project folder contains the following files and folders:

[image]

The dist folder contains the output files and folders from src. As you can recognize, I am using RollupJS as a module bundler.

The question is when I publish the project to NPM registry, it is enough to publish only the dist folder, or do I have to publish all files and folders?

```
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import setting from "./package.json";

export default {
    input: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        file: setting.main,
        format: "es",
    },
    plugins: [typescript(), peerDepsExternal(), nodeResolve()]
};
```

The content of `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "@example/components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "React components",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.es.js",
  "author": "anujit marty",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup --config"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.44.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.30.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pushing `dist` to npm is enough. After you run the build command, all the files that are required for the package to run properly, are compiled into the dist folder, thus removing the need to push the entire project.

Comment: The files and folders that I do not need, can I mention it in the `.npmignore` file?

Comment: `.npmignore` functions the same way `.gitignore` does and allows you to specify files that you do not to be uploaded to the npm registry. So, if you want npm to ignore certain files, when uploading the package, you can specify them in `.npmignore`